# pip install not working in colab for trumania Library

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
!pip install trumania
```

whenever,I run the above command i get the below mentioned error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement trumania
ERROR: No matching distribution found for trumania
```

Comment: The **trumania** library does not exist. https://pypi.org/search/?q=trumania

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it with

```
!pip install faker
!npx degit RealImpactAnalytics/trumania/trumania trumania
```

Then you can import from the cloned folder

```
from trumania.core import *
```