# Why can't I install the Trumania package on my macOs/ VScode?

Tags: python

I'm trying to download Trumania by using
`!npx degit RealImpactAnalytics/trumania/trumania trumania`
in my terminal (Mac), but it doesn't work.

I get this '[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnxha.png)' all the time.
And it doesn't work in Visual Studio Code. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKCjN.png) is the error I get in VS. So I'm
not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: What do you mean "all the time"? The message indicates it worked once to clone the repo, now the folder is not empty... `npx` is for NodeJS, not Python, so its unclear what you expect to be installed. After you activate the conda env, you need to install the module to that environment using `conda` or `pip install`

Comment: @OneCricketeer I mean that I get the same error every time I try to install it, although I tried to install everything from the start. So I'm not sure anymore what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
pip install faker
npx degit RealImpactAnalytics/trumania/trumania trumania
```

Then it should be working:

```
from trumania.core import *
```

You can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65340616/pip-install-not-working-in-colab-for-trumania-library)

**Update:**

You have installed the `trumania` successfully, so when you install it again you will get the error message of `destination directory is not empty, aborting. Use --force to override`.

And you should find the `trumania` folder under your project. But as the path of `workspace` folder does not exist in the `PYTHONPATH`, so the VSCode still can not find this module.

So you can move this module to some location in the `PYTHONPATH`:

> move this module to the `site-packages` folder(the python interpreter
> you are using)

Or add the parent folder of `trumania` to the PYTHONPATH(settings.json).

> ```
>   "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
>     "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder};"
>   },
> ```

Comment: Hi, I still get this message: `! destination directory is not empty, aborting. Use --force to override.` but now it's red instead of blue.

Comment: @Rky Da Could you have a look at the update?

Comment: @Rky `npx degit` is similar to `git clone`, which returns a warning if the folder you're cloning into is not empty. That warning is not related to your Python code. Since you've already cloned the repo, you don't need to run that command more than once